# Oarsub job with subprocess.run() script

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

l have an **oarsub** job to lunch with `subprocess.run()`.

I created a file named **script.py** as follow :

```
import subprocess
host_nb = 2
nb_core = 16
log_name = "./home/get_results.sh"

subprocess.run(["oarsub",
                cmd,
                "-p host='big{}'".format(host_nb),
                "-l core={}".format(nb_core),
                "-E oar_ouputs/%s.stderr" % log_name,
                "-O oar_outputs/%s.stdout" % log_name,
                "--notify".format("taylor_jason80@yahoo.com")
                ])
```

When l run in my terminal the following command :

```
python script.py cmd
```

l get the following error

**cmd,NameError: name 'cmd' is not defined**

Comment: *Inside your script*, where is `cmd` defined?  What do you want it to be?  Is that a placeholder you're using for us only or is that what you're actually typing

Comment: It is not defined . It's what l'm actually typing

Comment: Okay then you need to "bring it in" to your script, via `sys.argv` (as suggested in the answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the first argument passed in on the command line, it's available as `sys.argv[1]`.

If you want that to be assigned to the variable `cmd`, do

```
import subprocess
import sys

host_nb = 2
nb_core = 16
log_name = "./home/get_results.sh"
cmd = sys.argv[1]

# etc...
```

Do note that you'll need to quote arguments with spaces on the command line, e.g.

```
python script.py "this will all be sys.argv[1]"
```